# Shell function exiting early rather than looping through all contents

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to iterate over a list of users, but this code is terminating after the first deletion. What's wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash

       function delete_users() {
          echo "Deleting system users"
          local USERS_TO_DELETE="test test2 test3"
          for USER in $USERS_TO_DELETE
             do
                local USER_EXIST=$(getent passwd ${USER})
                   if [ -z "$USER_EXIST" ]
                      then
                         echo "User $USER does not exist"
                   elif [ -n "$USER_EXIST" ]
                      then
                         exec userdel $USER
                         echo "Successfully deleted $USER account"
                    fi
              done
          return 0
            }

      delete_users
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are using `exec`. The `exec` command will *replace* the current shell (in this case, the subshell that your script is running in) with the specified command. So once your script hits the `exec userdel $USER` line, your script goes poof and is replaced by a single instance of the `userdel` command.

Comment: `USERS_TO_DELETE` isn't an array at all in your code -- it's a string. Bash *does* support arrays, but you need to use array syntax if you want to have an array.

Comment: ...but yes, `exec` is indeed your problem here; it's nothing to do with deleting anything from any array you may or may not have.

Comment: (By the way, all-caps names are reserved; your own variables should use lower-case names. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace -- following this convention avoids overwriting system-impacting variables by mistake).

Comment: ...you might also consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- and avoiding the `function` keyword, which makes your code incompatible with baseline POSIX but adding no functionality over the more compatible function declaration syntax (which is just `delete_users() { : "content here"; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is running `exec userdel`.

The `exec` keyword [when used in this context, rather than with a redirection list alone] tells the shell to directly use an `execv`-family syscall to invoke `userdel` with no preceding `fork()`. This means that the shell no longer exists -- its process-table entry is directly replaced with that of `userdel`.

Comment: This.  Normally, the shell runs commands by launching a new process, and then waits for that new process to terminate before proceeding to the next command.  But when you use `exec`, it doesn't create a new process; it just *replaces itself* with the other command.  So there is no shell waiting for the command to complete that could pick up your script where it left off; the shell self-destructed by launching the command.

Comment: In fact, the shell runs a new command by first forking itself (so that there are two, identical copies of the process), then the new copy uses `exec` to replace itself with the desired command.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
USERS_TO_DELETE="test test2 test3"
```

to

```
USERS_TO_DELETE=(test test2 test3)
```

and

```
for USER in $USERS_TO_DELETE
```

to

```
for USER in "${USERS_TO_DELETE[@]}" #Double quote to avoid re-splitting elements though nbd here
```

Also

```
exec userdel "$USER" # exec replaces the current shell with a new instance
```

should be

```
if userdel "$USER"  #introduced some error checking 
then
echo "Successfully deleted $USER account"
fi
```

Comment: If you're going to do a best-practices rewrite, might as well also point out the missing quoting (and avoid introducing more).

Comment: And better to suggest `if userdel $user; then ...` than checking `$?` -- and moving to non-conflicting names; $USER in particular is often going to be set to the current user's name by other system components, so it's best not to overwrite it.